# Map marker on Google Android Maps API v2 with set bounds

Tags: android, google-maps, bounds

In APIv1 I was drawing markers like this:

```
    Drawable flag = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.flagfinish);
    flag.setBounds(0, -flag.getIntrinsicHeight(), flag.getIntrinsicWidth(), 0);
```

and it was working - left bottom corner of picture was in center of LatLng. But how could I draw something like this in APIv2? I tried this:

```
Marker hc = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(HC)
        .title("Hlohovec")
        .snippet("Hlohovec")
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.flagfinish)));
```

but this is moved to left (I want to draw a flag with pole on left so this doesn't pin it where I want).

Is there any possible way to do this? And I don't want to use `GroundOverlayOptions` because it is changing with zoom.

Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to change the `Anchor` position of the marker image when you create the marker

from the docs:

`The point on the image that will be placed at the LatLng position of the marker. This defaults to the middle of the bottom of the image.`

Comment: Thank You very much! Exactly what I was looking for. For complete information if needed: left bottom corner of image -> `.anchor(0, 1)`

Comment: @Tunerx Note that you will have an issue like [Issue 5131](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5131) if you use info window.

Comment: thanks, the problem is there... but it is not that big an issue, it doesn't look very bad with my icons :)